# why increasing the number of blocks in cuda increase the time?

Tags: cuda

My understanding is that in CUDA, increase the number of blocks will not increase the time as they are implemented parallelly, but in my code, if I double the number of blocks, the time doubled as well.

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <curand.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

#define num_of_blocks 500
#define num_of_threads 512

__constant__ double y = 1.1;

// set seed for random number generator
__global__ void initcuRand(curandState* globalState, unsigned long seed){
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    curand_init(seed, idx, 0, &globalState[idx]);
}

// kernel function for SIR
__global__ void test(curandState* globalState, double *dev_data){
    // global threads id
    int idx     = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    // local threads id
    int lidx    = threadIdx.x;

    // creat shared memory to store seeds
    __shared__ curandState localState[num_of_threads];

    // shared memory to store samples
    __shared__ double sample[num_of_threads];

    // copy global seed to local
    localState[lidx]    = globalState[idx];
    __syncthreads();

    sample[lidx]    =  y + curand_normal_double(&localState[lidx]);

    if(lidx == 0){
        // save the first sample to dev_data;
        dev_data[blockIdx.x] = sample[0];
    }

    globalState[idx]    = localState[lidx];
}

int main(){
    // creat random number seeds;
    curandState *globalState;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&globalState, num_of_blocks*num_of_threads*sizeof(curandState));
    initcuRand<<<num_of_blocks, num_of_threads>>>(globalState, 1);

    double *dev_data;
    cudaMalloc((double**)&dev_data, num_of_blocks*sizeof(double));

    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    // Start record
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    test<<<num_of_blocks, num_of_threads>>>(globalState, dev_data);

    // Stop event
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    float elapsedTime;
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime, start, stop); // that's our time!
    // Clean up:
    cudaEventDestroy(start);
    cudaEventDestroy(stop);

    std::cout << "Time ellapsed: " << elapsedTime << std::endl;

    cudaFree(dev_data);
    cudaFree(globalState);
    return 0;
}
```

The test result is:

```
number of blocks: 500, Time ellapsed: 0.39136.
number of blocks: 1000, Time ellapsed: 0.618656.
```

So what is the reason that the time will increase? Is it because I access the constant memory or I copy the data from shared memory to global memory? Is that some ways to optimise it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the number of blocks being able to run in parallel can be large, it is still finite due to limited on-chip resources. If the number of blocks requested in a kernel launch exceeds that limit, any further blocks have to wait for earlier blocks to finish and free up their resources.

One limited resource is shared memory, of which your kernel uses 28 kilobytes. CUDA 8.0 compatible Nvidia GPUs offer between 48 and 112 kilobytes of shared memory per streaming multiprocessor (SM), so that the maximum number of blocks running at any one time is between 1× and 3× the number of SMs on your GPU.

Other limited resources are registers and various per-warp resources in the scheduler. The [CUDA occupancy calculator](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/CUDA_Occupancy_calculator.xls) is a convenient Excel spreadsheet (also works with OpenOffice/LibreOffice) that shows you how these resources limit the number of blocks per SM for a specific kernel. Compile the kernel adding the option `--ptxas-options="-v"` to the `nvcc` command line, locate the line saying "ptxas info    : Used *XX* registers, *YY* bytes smem, *zz* bytes cmem[0], *ww* bytes cmem[2]", and enter *XX*, *YY*, the number of threads per block you are trying to launch, and the compute capability of your GPU into the spreadsheet. It will then show the maximum number of blocks that can run in parallel on one SM.

You don't mention the GPU you have been running the test on, so I'll use a GTX 980 as an example. It has 16 SMs with 96Kb of shared memory each, so at most 16×3=48 blocks can run in parallel. Had you not used shared memory, the maximum number of resident warps would have limited the number of blocks per SM to 4, allowing 64 blocks to run in parallel.

On any currently existing Nvidia GPU, your example requires at least about a dozen waves of blocks executing sequentially, explaining why doubling the number of blocks will also about double the runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The GPU I am using is Tesla K80, where I can get the number of streaming multiprocessor it has? In addition, it is only for one GPU, if I use two GPUs to run the code, does it make sense, i.e, with maximum blocks each GPU can run concurrently and we have more GPUs, will the time increase?

Comment: For the Tesla lineup, that information is a bit harder to come by than for the GeForce cards, where for the latter you can just look up the specs on their website. I've never been able to find similar information for the professional cards (never quite understood why - the Tesla marketing material on Nvidia's website seems to be directed at the managers making the purchase decision, on the apparent assumption they can't read or understand technical specifications).

Comment: That rant aside, you can obtain the info by combining the facts that [K80 has 2496 single precision  "CUDA cores"](http://international.download.nvidia.com/pdf/kepler/TeslaK80-datasheet.pdf) per GPU and that [a single GK110/GK210 SM has 192 single precision "CUDA cores" per SM](http://images.nvidia.com/content/pdf/tesla/NVIDIA-Kepler-GK110-GK210-Architecture-Whitepaper.pdf) to find that each of the two GPUs on a K80 has 13 SMs.

Comment: However, work is not automatically spread between the two GPUs on the K80. You have to split the work yourself, by explicitly launching one kernel on each of the GPUs, each which half the number of blocks you want to run. You'll also have to copy all supporting data to both of the GPU's, as they do not share a common address space (they really are separate devices on a single printed circuit board).

Comment: thanks for this information. I tested the with 16 cores on K80 and it is the same time as I launched 2 blocks. In fact, in my code, the shared memory is fully used, even I can not launch 512 threads. I have a quiz more, if I launch more blocks on different GPU, will it take long time for them to communicate between each of them?

Comment: Kernels launched on different GPUs don't communicate with each other (unless you've explicitly programmed that using peer-to-peer memory access). However you'll have to copy all necessary data to both devices yourself, which could increase the runtime.

Comment: I missed earlier that GK210 is of compute capability 3.7, so it has 112kb of shared memory in default configuration. That is just enough to run your kernel with 4 blocks/SM, for a total of 52 blocks per GPU. All conclusions remain unchanged though.